# Symfony - AsseticBundle - AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony

Today I installed Symfony, but I don't know this framework and I have a problem:

When I want to open my project in the browser, I see error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\AppKernel.php on line 16
```

I opened folder "Symfony\Bundle" and I don't see 'AsseticBundle' folder. So what wrong I did? How can I fix this issue?

and Happy Easter everyone!

Comment: The Assetic bundle is referenced but cannot be resolved by the autoloader, did you run `composer install`?

Comment: You mean that : https://getcomposer.org/download/ ? I downloaded and installed, but didn't help.

I have a clue, because at the moment I installed the latest version Symfony 3.2.7 , but project what I use in composer.json has "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*", it can be source of the problem?

Comment: Just follow the original installation documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Comment: The version mismatch sounds like a solid source for errors, try to re-install as mentioned by @Confidence

Comment: @Confidence thank you very much, I installed this same version what use project and work fine.